# Extract a 2-element tuple and convert it to String

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, tuples

So I have a list of random words like this:

```
[('Frenchy', 'INTENSE'), ('Frenchy', 'ComputerScienceFTW'), ('Frenchy', 'HelloMrGumby'), ('INTENSE', 'Frenchy'), ('INTENSE', 'ComputerScienceFTW'), ('INTENSE', 'HelloMrGumby'), ('ComputerScienceFTW', 'Frenchy'), ('ComputerScienceFTW', 'INTENSE'), ('ComputerScienceFTW', 'HelloMrGumby'), ('HelloMrGumby', 'Frenchy'), ('HelloMrGumby', 'INTENSE'), ('HelloMrGumby', 'ComputerScienceFTW')]
```

which is a product of permutation. Now that I have this, I wish to add the item in the tuple together like this:

```
[('Frenchy', 'INTENSE')] # Was this
'FrenchyINTENSE' # Now this
```

Is there a way to do it elegantly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a list comprehension to join them; this is easiest with the [`str.join()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
[''.join(t) for t in list_of_tuples]
```

but you could also use unpacking and straight-up concatenation:

```
[a + b for a, b in list_of_tuples]
```

The `str.join()` method has the advantage that'll work for sequences of arbitrary length.

Demo:

```
>>> list_of_tuples = [('Frenchy', 'INTENSE'), ('Frenchy', 'ComputerScienceFTW'), ('Frenchy', 'HelloMrGumby'), ('INTENSE', 'Frenchy'), ('INTENSE', 'ComputerScienceFTW'), ('INTENSE', 'HelloMrGumby'), ('ComputerScienceFTW', 'Frenchy'), ('ComputerScienceFTW', 'INTENSE'), ('ComputerScienceFTW', 'HelloMrGumby'), ('HelloMrGumby', 'Frenchy'), ('HelloMrGumby', 'INTENSE'), ('HelloMrGumby', 'ComputerScienceFTW')]
>>> [''.join(t) for t in list_of_tuples]
['FrenchyINTENSE', 'FrenchyComputerScienceFTW', 'FrenchyHelloMrGumby', 'INTENSEFrenchy', 'INTENSEComputerScienceFTW', 'INTENSEHelloMrGumby', 'ComputerScienceFTWFrenchy', 'ComputerScienceFTWINTENSE', 'ComputerScienceFTWHelloMrGumby', 'HelloMrGumbyFrenchy', 'HelloMrGumbyINTENSE', 'HelloMrGumbyComputerScienceFTW']
>>> [a + b for a, b in list_of_tuples]
['FrenchyINTENSE', 'FrenchyComputerScienceFTW', 'FrenchyHelloMrGumby', 'INTENSEFrenchy', 'INTENSEComputerScienceFTW', 'INTENSEHelloMrGumby', 'ComputerScienceFTWFrenchy', 'ComputerScienceFTWINTENSE', 'ComputerScienceFTWHelloMrGumby', 'HelloMrGumbyFrenchy', 'HelloMrGumbyINTENSE', 'HelloMrGumbyComputerScienceFTW']
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a list comprehesion. Unpack each tuple of strings and add the strings together.

```
>>> lst = [('Frenchy', 'INTENSE'), ('Frenchy', 'ComputerScienceFTW')]
>>> [a+b for a,b in lst]
['FrenchyINTENSE', 'FrenchyComputerScienceFTW']
```

Answer (score 2):

For bigger iterables (and memory efficient usage) you maybe want to use something from itertools module, like [starmap](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap) function:

```
import itertools

tuples = [('Frenchy', 'INTENSE'), ('Frenchy', 'ComputerScienceFTW'),]

result = itertools.starmap(lambda a, b: a + b, tuples)
```

And of course, this is a elegantly way to go too.